# What is a good delivery format from a server to a utility app?

Tags: iphone, web-services, utility

What Format should data be in when going into a utility app from a server? JSON, XML or something else?

*Edit:*

I need to tell a client to tell his web guy to build me a web service or let me do it. I need to make sure I am asking for the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best format is Apple's Plist format. The iPhone OS can quickly and easily parse this. It's faster and less memory intensive than XML.

Best of all, it requires no additional libraries or parsing code on the device.

Comment: Technically, it is XML. But I understand what you mean. Just to elaborate, list data can be very easily transformed into NSDictionaries, NSArrays, NSStrings, NSNumbers, etc. using initWithContentsOfFile: Very useful. (+1)

Comment: How would my serverside script make a plist? Generate the XML and save it as a .plist, or generate and serve it?

Comment: Generate and serve it. I believe there are open source classes that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are good libraries for parsing and emitting both XML and JSON in Cocoa Touch.  I recommend [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/) and either [Stig Brautaset's JSON](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) or [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON).

Comment: Which one would you recommend ?